# Dúvida sobre como usar fazer uma tela para medir temperatura pelo celular

Tags: android

me tirem uma dúvida, tenho que adicionar uma função de medir a temperatura do ambiente pelo smartphone no meu app android, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, e nem sei se tem como...
Alguém poderia só me dar uma dica, ou dizer se não tem como? kkkk

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Sua dúvida é bem parecida com essa:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931681/how-to-get-device-s-temperature-in-android

e essa:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985396/is-there-any-android-api-to-find-sense-room-temperature-programmatically-in-andr

Você pode usar 
[TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE)
 para verificar a temperatura da cpu ou bateria.

Olha o exemplo que é dado:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;

public class TempSensorActivity extends Activity, implements SensorEventListener {
 private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private final Sensor mTempSensor;

 public TempSensorActivity() {
     mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
     mTempSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
 }

 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mTempSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
 }

 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
 }

 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
 }

 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
 }
}
```

Dá uma olhada aqui: [SensorManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)

Comment: Edjane muito obrigado pela ajuda